# SCDF Spring Cloud Data Fflow problems with task-launcher-dataflow Incompatible version of Data Flow server detected

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

I Build a stream with sftp-dataflow as source (sftp-dataflow-source-kafka:2.1.1.RELEASE) connected with task-launcher-dataflow (task-launcher-dataflow-sink-kafka:1.0.2.RELEASE) as sink. The goal is to launch a task which is a spring-batch job.

My SCDF platform contains : Skipper-server version 2.3.0, dataflow-server 2.4.0 and kafka deployed as dockers.

The sftp source send a message to the task-launcher and the launcher have an exception :

> Failed to instantiate
>   [org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.rest.client.DataFlowOperations]:
>   Factory method 'dataFlowOperations' threw exception; nested exception
>   is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Incompatible version of Data Flow
>   server detected.

All my components are in the last versions.

To create may stream:

```
stream create testStreamSftpDataflowlaunch1 --definition "sftp-dataflow --local-dir=/tmp/local-files1 --remote-dir=/data/docker/containers/SCDF/dockerSCDF/tmp/remote-files1 --password=docker* --allow-unknown-keys=true --username=docker --host=slnxdalicrprp03.mano.es.sopra --task-name=batchEODTask --logging.level.org.springframework.integration=DEBUG --task.launch.request.taskName=batchEODTask | task-launcher-dataflow --server-uri=http://slnxdalicrprp03******:57102" (skipper-server;port)
```

Other thing, I don't understand, how the launcher can execute a task because the task-name is not transmit to the launcher through the message. For example, we have the file name and others properties

> message: GenericMessage [payload=/tmp/local-files1/FMO.txt,
>   headers={file_originalFile=/tmp/local-files1/FMO.txt,
>   id=7447a3ab-cd0e-17c2-181d-7b0f5cb85d78, file_name=FMO.txt,
>   file_relativePath=FMO.txt, timestamp=1582106812595}] 2020-02-19
>   10:06:52.961 DEBUG 233 --- [ask-scheduler-1]
>   o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter      : Poll resulted in Message:
>   GenericMessage [payload=/tmp/local-files1/FMO2.txt,
>   headers={file_originalFile=/tmp/local-files1/FMO2.txt,
>   id=b0fc3c02-a3e2-2481-aa5b-68f9db6b6973, file_name=FMO2.txt,
>   file_relativePath=FMO2.txt, timestamp=1582106812961}] 2020-02-19
>   10:06:52.962 DEBUG 233 --- [ask-scheduler-1]
>   o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : preSend on channel
>   'taskLaunchRequestChannel',

When I launch the SCDF sample in documentation with the ingestFile, we have the same problem.

Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot in this post. I will attempt to unpack a few things here.

> The sftp source send a message to the task-launcher and the launcher have an exception : Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.dataflow.rest.client.DataFlowOperations]: Factory method 'dataFlowOperations' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Incompatible version of Data Flow server detected.

It appears the TL-Dataflow sink is bundled with rather an older SCDF client library — see [tasklauncher-dataflow-app-dependencies/pom.xml#L20](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tasklauncher-dataflow/blob/master/tasklauncher-dataflow-app-dependencies/pom.xml#L20). You can update the version to 2.4.0.RELEASE (same as SCDF that you have got running already), and [build the app](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tasklauncher-dataflow/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-task-launcher-dataflow/README.adoc#build) and as well a local docker image for your testing/use.

> Other thing, I don't understand, how the launcher can execute a task because the task-name is not transmit to the launcher through the message.

If you pay attention to TL-Dataflow docs, you will notice the [input](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tasklauncher-dataflow/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-task-launcher-dataflow/README.adoc#input) (aka payload) is accepted as a JSON with certain key/value pairs. The `name` is the critical bit. It is the name of the Task definition that already exists in SCDF. We have an [end-to-end recipe](https://dataflow.spring.io/docs/recipes/file-ingest/sftp-to-jdbc/) that walk through the use-case entirely, which you can use as the reference and follow along.

Recently, we also added the enhancement to auto-create the task definition (if there's none). The `name` must match with an existing task-app name in the app registry — see [spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tasklauncher-dataflow#24](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tasklauncher-dataflow/issues/24).

I believe this covers the pressing questions on this post.

Comment: I just also opened [spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tasklauncher-dataflow#32](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/tasklauncher-dataflow/issues/32) for tracking — feel free to share your findings with the local patch and testing.

Comment: OK thanks for your answer and the track opening. Do you have a date for the new version of this component?. Here we investigate the error and try to patch this component. But to upgrade the <spring.cloud.dataflow.version>2.4.0.RELEASE</spring.cloud.dataflow.version> needs to upgrade others dependencies and a part of code must be review.  Regards

Comment: Feel free to start a PR against #32 — we can collaborate to bring it together.